# 2FA with blower.io SMS

Tags: multi-factor, sms, django

I'm currently planning to deploy a project on Heroku and was wondering if it is safe to send 2FA sms messages with the [blower.io heroku addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/blowerio)?
Also is it safe/ok to send a short lived authentication code by sms or is there any way to send secure SMS messages?

Answer (score 0):

Very good explanation why sms 2FA is bad idea: https://blog.sucuri.net/2020/01/why-2fa-sms-is-a-bad-idea.html

I recommend to use [TOTP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6238) because it works offline.

Comment: Please summarize here what the link says. It goes offline and your answer is left with almost nothing.

Comment: I read the article, and it talks about sending an authentication message back through text, but that is not what I want to do. The process I was thinking is:
1. Detect action that requires 2FA 2. Server generates generates hash from random password. 3. User gets text message containing password. 4. Server checks password results in same password and that it is entered from them same origin as the original event that triggered the 2FA.

Comment: @Jonatan I think sms not the best way for security delivery. But if you insist on sms you can do this. Hashing password on server side is excessive, because it doesn’t protect against anything.